# Does e2fsck command print process ID when it fails with the error "is in use" with verbose mode?

Tags: bash, fsck

Is the process ID printed as output for command `e2fsck -vyf` when it fails with the error "is in use"?

Answer (score 1):

No. The "in use" refers to the device that is supposed to be checked.

It shows this somewhat like ...

```
# fsck -f /dev/sdX
...
/dev/sdX is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

If you need users and the process-IDs of processes from those users you can user `fuser` for that.

Comment: Is it the same with the verbose mode?